# class R не создается при слиянии исходного кода библиотеки с проектом

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть проект и его исходный код лежит в `main/java/example` так же есть код в папке `main/java/com` В `com` исходный код библиотеки.

Вот в директории, где создаются `R` классы в папке `example` создается `R` класс, а папка `com` с `R` классом не появляется. А должна, так как в коде есть импорт этого класса. Если подключить `aar` библиотеку через зависимости этот `R` класс появляется.

Ну я думаю мне копать надо начиная с **вопроса:**

В какой момент создается `R` класс, может надо где то запись добавить какую-то? Пока что я просто скопировал `R` класс, который появляется при подключении библиотеки, но ведь он должен как то сам появиться.

**UPD**

Копирование `R` класса не помогает, при запуске приложения он удаляется.. Зачем он нужен этот класс я знаю ну очень поверхностно, пока не вникал и это не суть вопроса. Мне нужен ответ на то, как мне его создать. А со смыслом я позже разберусь

**UPD1** 
По пути `AndroidStudioProjects\app\src\main\java\example\i` лежал код моего проекта. Код библиотеки добавил по пути `AndroidStudioProjects\app\src\main\java\com\vk\sdk` . Не важно какая это библиотека. Я пробовал разные библиотеки добавлять, но R класс создается только для кода лежащего по пути `AndroidStudioProjects\app\src\main\java\example\i`    И естественно ругается на отсутствие класса  `import com.vk.sdk.R;` и всё подобное `findViewById(R.id.captchaAnswer);` подсвечено красным, т.к. нет идентификаторов ресурсов.
 **UPD2** 
папка где появляются R классы `C:\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\app\build\generated\source\r\debug`   Если подлючить библиотеку через зависимости ,  R класс появится.  Я его вырезаю. отключаю зависимости. вставляю вырезанный класс. Но при запуске приложения он удаляется. Т.е. где то есть Указание для какого кода R class создается.

Очистки проекта, кэша и пересборку пробовал.

**UPD3**
Если переформулировать вопрос короче, то не создаются `R.class` для других `package` ,которые лежат в папке `src\main\java\` , кроме первого созданного `package`

Comment: Покажите как у вас библиотека подключена в обих случаях.

Comment: В случае ,когда библиотека подключается через зависимости проблемы нет . Я же хочу просто слить java файлы моего проекта с java файлами библиотеки.    dependencies {
        compile(name:'androidsdk-1.6.3', ext:'aar')
    }   Мне нужно поэкспериментировать с одним классом этой библиотеки,нужно править его код.

Comment: Думаю, вам надо подключить либу как модуль. Так вы сможете править её код

Comment: Что плохого в том ,чтобы просто слить код библиотеки с кодом проекта ?  Как модуль она не подключилась у меня.  Правда  я код сохранил в другом package

Comment: Ну, хотя бы затем, чтобы было удобно и правильно. Если вам либу надо потестить вживую - подключите её как проект. Если она будет не нужна - просто удаляете одну строку. Если нужна - оставляете как есть или меняете строку на зависимость к aar файлу. Это же гораздо проще чем встраивать много кода, решать конфликты, а потом ещё и выпиливать обратно всё это

Comment: ну не получилось как модуль. Я прочитал , что нужно чтобы подключить как модуль. НАписано, что исходные коды должны быть gradle-проектом. Но в этой библиотеке нет никаких расширений файлов ,кроме как java . Import  module ничего не видит.

Comment: Еще есть файл манифеста. Но тем не менее импорт модуля пишет : specify location of the Gradle or Android Eclipse project . Делаю вывод , что я не могу подключить эту библиотеку как модуль

Comment: Ну, тогда надо хоть что-то увидеть, раз у вас такая нестандартная проблема. Неужто в логах ничего нет, никакой ругани? Ссылок дайте на либу, например. По имеющейся информации почти ничего нельзя подсказать более

Comment: Сейчас дополню вопрос.

Comment: Ну... Может в example/i положить библиотеку?

Comment: Я тоже так подумал, но в библиотеке файлы лежат в иерархии папок. А в классах другой библиотеки, которая опирается на эту библиотеку куча импортов с учетом этой иерархии папок.  Вопрос в том, можно ли создавать папки в или код все java должны лежать в одной папке. Скорее можно и проблема в чем то другом. Я попробую чуть позже поэкспериментировать и переместить часть кода,чтобы увидеть в этом ли проблема.  Еще один момент дополнил в вопросе.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, я понял в чем была проблема. Сперва заметил в вопросах на форумах, что R.class не генерируется , если есть ошибки где то в ресурсах. Посмотрел, а оказывается в aar библиотеке, из которой я выдернул весь исходный код , есть множество loyaut и других ресурсов. Их очень много и очень проблемно всё это внедрять в своей проект. Надо разобраться как это подключить как модуль, но это уже другой вопрос. Спасибо